# Scoping, variable access in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, scope, callback, delegates

In Javascript, an inner function has access to an outer function's variables. So in the below example, `objFlag` is accessible within the `this.depthTraverse` function.

```
Tree.prototype.findNodeWithValue = function(valueToFind){
    var objFlag = {found: false, node: null}
    this.depthTraverse(function(foundNode){
        if(foundNode.data === valueToFind){
            objFlag.found = true;
            objFlag.node = foundNode;
        }
    })
    return objFlag
}
```

I'm trying to write the equivalent in C# in the same sort of manner but realizing I'm coming across some scoping issues. FWIW, I am not well versed using delegates, func, or action so I could certainly be missing things, but to me, it seems like even if I can pass around a method in C#, it would not have access to any outer variables of the function it's getting called in? Is there a way to write what is inherently the equivalent to the above code, but in C#? And I'm not asking for the same output or result, I'm asking for the same way of passing in a function and mutating outer variable state.

`depthTraverse` implementation below for reference:

```
Tree.prototype.depthTraverse = function(fn){
    var queue = [];
    queue.push(this.root);
    while(queue.length > 0){
        var nodeToInspect = queue.pop();
        if(nodeToInspect.leaves.length !== 0){
            queue.unshift(...nodeToInspect.leaves) // breadth first
        }
        if(fn){
            fn(nodeToInspect);
        }
    }
}
```

------ UPDATE ------

I believe I came to a solution based on @JonWeeder's answer. Below:

```
    private static Node<T> holder {get;set;}
    public Node<T> FindValue(T value){
        Node<T> node;
        TraverseDFS(value, (el) => {
            if(Comparer<T>.Equals(el.Value, value)){
                holder = el;
            }
        });
        node = holder;
        holder = null;
        return node == null ? null : node;
    }

    private void TraverseDFS(T value, Action<Node<T>> action)
    {
        var queue = new List<Node<T>>();
        queue.Add(this.Root);
        while(queue.Count > 0){
            var currentNode = queue[0];
            queue.RemoveAt(0);
            if(currentNode.Leaves.Count > 0){
                queue.AddRange(currentNode.Leaves);
            }
            action(currentNode);
        }
    }
```

This is as close as I could get the the Javascript's implementation. Though untested, IDE is not complaining.

Comment: https://asizikov.github.io/2016/04/15/thoughts-on-local-functions/

Comment: @zzxyz This example is an anonymous method, not a local method.

Comment: @Servy I think the article does a good job addressing the scoping problem, and provides solutions that work pre-C# 7.  I'm also not sure what example you are referring to.  If you mean the link, there are definitely several examples which are not anonymous.  I may be misunderstanding your point, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This rather simple example demonstrates that, essentially, C# can be made to work similarly to JS with respect to closures. **Action** specifies that the parameter passed in is a function which takes no arguments and returns nothing. **() =>**... is a way to define a simple lambda -- essentially an inline function.

```
    public class ObjFlag {  public bool Found { get; set; } }

    public void DoSomething(Action action)
    {
        action();
    }

    public void Sample()
    {
        var objFlag = new ObjFlag { Found = false };
        DoSomething(() => objFlag.Found = true);

        Assert.IsTrue(objFlag.Found);
    }
```

Comment: Maybe it makes sense to demonstrate multi-line variant of syntax for the lambda as well to improve this answer?

Comment: Thanks, I think I got to a solution from your example.

Answer (score 1):

As C# is a [statically typed language](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2012/10/15/is-c-a-strongly-typed-or-a-weakly-typed-language/), the code I wrote as an example looks a bit differently from your example, but I hope it does more or less the same thing. Please also have a look at Action<> and Func<> delegate types documentation or this [wonderful blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brunoterkaly/2012/03/02/c-delegates-actions-funcs-lambdaskeeping-it-super-simple/).

```
class Node
{
    public int Data { get; set; }
    // omitting other Node details here
}

class ObjFlag
{
    public Node Node { get; set; }
    public bool Found { get; set; }
}

class Tree
{
    public ObjFlag FindNodeWithValue(int valueToFind)
    {
        var objFlag = new ObjFlag() { Found = false, Node = null };
        DepthTraverse(node =>
        {
            if (node.Data == valueToFind)
            {
                objFlag.Node = node;
                objFlag.Found = true;
            }                
        });

        return objFlag;
    }

    public void DepthTraverse(Action<Node> action)
    {
        Node nodeToInspect = null;
        // some logic to get the node to inspect
        if (action != null)
            action(nodeToInspect);
    }
}
```